# Trying to find a quick method for $x! \pmod y$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I m trying to find a really quick method to calculate stuff like

$x! \pmod y~~
\text{where }~\{x,y:\text{y is a prime}\}\in \mathbb{N}$
and
$400\geq \{x,y\}\geq 50$ and $y>x+30$
$\text{Note : }$ Four options are given and the time limit to find is on an average  $5$ minutes per question in exam.
You can use any method (solution based, not procees based). Pen and Paper method. No calculators allowed.

I know there is a $\text{Wilson's theorem}$ but cannot help every time  as here as the difference between 
$x$ and $y$ can be little more.

example :

$73! \pmod {113}$

Here  $112! \pmod{113}\equiv-1$

How to proceed